# Distinguishing between elements with the same name in RobotFramework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a website with a table of links inside of it. There are two/three elements (links) in the table with the same name. The only thing that distinguishes them is the header above them

```
< h1 class="b4">Label 1< /h1>
```

Would be an example. How can I get RF to go the link under the header Label 2 as opposed to Label 1? I need something besides `xpath/css` because those change throughout the design.

Comment: It **is** possible to do that in Xpath using relative paths or axes. If you provide, a larger code snippet of your HTML page, I can show you how. The example code should contain at least two elements with the same name and their distinguishing header .

Comment: <div class="bU">

    <h1 class="b4">Header 1</h1>

    <a data-ajax="" class="b5" href="Link">Link1</a>

    <h1 class="b4">Header 2</h1>

    <a data-ajax="" class="b5 ca" href="Link">Link1</a></div>

Would be an example

Sorry, no idea how to edit code properly on this

Answer (score 0):

Given your example

```
<div class="bU"> 
<h1 class="b4">Header 1</h1> 
<a data-ajax="" class="b5" href="Link">Link1</a> 
<h1 class="b4">Header 2</h1> 
<a data-ajax="" class="b5 ca" href="Link">Link1</a>
</div>
```

the easiest (XPath) way to access the anchor elements is directly using their unique `class` attributes:

```
//a[@class='b5']
```

for the first

```
//a[@class='b5 ca']
```

for the second.

If - for whatever reason - you have to use a locator relative to the headers, use this (for the second anchor element):

```
//h1[text()='Header 2']/following::a
```